# angular-seed-advanced + breeze + ios/android = Could not find module 'breeze-client'

Tags: breeze, nativescript

I'm trying to incorporate breeze into angular-seed-advanced (https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced) using breeze's TempHire Angular reference project: (https://github.com/Breeze/temphire.angular). Everything went well until I ran the App on an Android device. I got this error at runtime (iOS emulator gave similar results):

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "breeze-client", relative to: app/tns_modules/
    com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:146)
    com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:55)
    com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
    com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:504)
    com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:499)
    com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:17)
    android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5405)
    android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/com.yourdomain.nativescript/files/app/app/modules/core/services/entity-manager-provider.js', line: 3, column: 23
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/com.yourdomain.nativescript/files/app/app/modules/core/services/index.js', line: 14, column: 33
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/com.yourdomain.nativescript/files/app/app/modules/core/index.js', line: 6, column: 10
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/com.yourdomain.nativescript/files/app/native.module.js', line: 11, column: 15
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/com.yourdomain.nativescript/files/app/app.js', line: 5, column: 23
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
```

<s>I think this is a Webpack config issue of nativescript. Because first, the compile succeeded. So the compiler could find the 'breeze-client' module without issue. Secondly, the App works well in Web Browsers, which uses systemjs. But systemjs uses a different config file. I'm not familiar with WebPack config file.</s>

**EDIT:**
I think I found where the problem is but still don't know how to fix it:

During `tns build android`, `node_modules\*` are copied to `tns_modules\*`, which will be used in the Mobile App. However, files like `breeze.debug.js` are renamed to `breeze.js` during the build process (`.debug` is removed). Later when the App runs, CommonJS tries to load the `breeze.client` module. It checks the `package.json` file under `tns_modules\breeze-client` to see that `"main": "./breeze.debug.js"`, but the file is not there.

I wonder if there is a configuration somewhere to prevent renaming of `breeze.debug.js` to `breeze.js` during the build process.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should implement the native adapters for breeze instead of the web one. Look in the Breeze organization for one for Java, and another for ObjC/Swift.

Comment: @pkanev, Thanks, I will take a look. But isn't this defecting the purpose of using a framework like NativeScript? I will have to maintain platform specific code for things that are not platform specific.

Comment: You are forgetting that NativeScript still runs on a mobile platform, and must thus follow a fixed ruleset. A shim for all node/web things can probably be made, and that still won't mean that running a web/nodejs module on a mobile device is more optimal, than the mobile sdk itself. The purpose of plugins is to wrap them once, and use them everywhere.

Not saying you should use the mobile sdks at all costs, if it were Cordova, or Ionic, you would probably get away with using the web drivers... those are web platforms after all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with angular-seed, but it *looks* like you need to add `breeze-client` to the `APP_ASSETS` array in [project.config.ts](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced/blob/master/tools/config/project.config.ts).

Then it should include the breeze library in the modules.

Comment: Do you mean I should do something like this: ```this.APP_ASSETS = [
      {src: `${this.APP_SRC}/node_modules/breeze-client/*`, inject: true, vendor: true}```? I tried it but it didn't work for me. It seems like `APP_ASSETS` is for including 'local' third party library to index.html. But breeze-client is an npm package. Again, this only happens on NativeScript build so I think I need to put this somewhere in the Webpack config files.

Comment: Could you take a look at my edits? This might be an issue in the NativeScript build process.